# Best way to pass parameter while using RxJS forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject, fork-join, subject

So, I have a service that has three functions that I need to execute.

I use `forkJoin` because I want to take further action when a response has been received for all!
One of them needs to receive one parameter.

```
getDevices(id: string): Observable<IEquipmentRow[]> {
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<IGetDevicesResponse>(url)
      .pipe(
        map(res => {
          return res.data;
        })
      );
}

private regions$ = this.getRegions();
private devices$ = this.getDevices();


public equipmentPreparationData$ = forkJoin({
    regions: this.regions$,
    devices: this.devices$
});
```

What is the best way to implement that? Maybe using `RxJS` `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject`?
What about `RxJS` `switchMap`, can we use it here?
I am new with `RxJS`, so be gentle :)

Comment: Do you mean you need to pass the `id` parameter to `getDevices()` when passing it to forkJoin?

Comment: @daflodedeing If it is possible, sure, but  I don't know how? If I use RxJS Subject, maybe, I don't need parameter passing...

Comment: Why don't you call this.getDevices() directly inside the forkjoin?

Comment: @Shifenis okej, but what about id parameter? I need it for HTTP request!

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do or what is the problem...

Comment: @martin sorry to hear that :/. How can I improve this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```js
// Change your response type
public equipmentPreparationData$(deviceID: string): Observable<any> {
 return forkJoin({
    regions: this.regions$,
    devices: this.getDevices(deviceID)
});


private getDevices(id: string): Observable<IEquipmentRow[]> {
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<IGetDevicesResponse>(url)
      .pipe(
        map(res => {
          return res.data;
        })
      );
}

private regions$ = this.getRegions();
```

In this way, you can use your function with the parameter and pass through `getDevices` method

Answer (score 0):

Also, possible `solution` using `combineLatest` and `mergeMap` for passing id parameter:

```
  public woidSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  public woidObservable: Observable<string> = this.woidSubject.asObservable();
  
  private devices$ = this.woidObservable.pipe(
    mergeMap(x => {
      debugger;
      return this.getDevices(x);
    })
  );

  public equipmentPreparationData$ = combineLatest([
    this.regions$,
    this.devices$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([regions, resourceTypes, devices]) => {
      return { regions: regions, devices: devices }
    })
  );
```

You can change id parameter from component like this:

```
this.service.woidSubject.next("3243");
```